# Node function not working, await part is not getting executed in the given function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, axios

While hitting API I'm getting function from my services/ElasticSearch.js and for some reason function there is not working after the axios part.

In the below file I've called function elasticService.updateDocument this function has been brought from another file.

'''

```
class ProductController {
  constructor() { }
  async saveProduct(req, res) {
    console.log('ITs coming here')
    let { _id, Product } = req.body;
    if (_id) delete req.body._id;
    let elasticResult;
    try {
      if (Product && Product.Category) {
        req.body.Category = Product.Category
        delete Product.Category
      }
      if (Product && Product.URL) {
        const exists = await ProductService.checkProductByUrl(Product.URL);
        _id = exists._id
      }
      const result = await ProductService.saveProduct(req.body, _id);
      if (result) {
        if (_id) {
          console.log('Here.... UPDATE')
          const savedProduct = await ProductModel.createPayload(req.body);
          console.log(savedProduct,'saved_product')
          let elaticDoc = await this.createElasticDocData(savedProduct);
          console.log(elaticDoc.id,'elasticResult')
          elaticDoc.id = result._id;
          elaticDoc = new Elastic(elaticDoc);
          console.log(elaticDoc,'<----------elaticdoc-------------->')
          elasticResult = await elasticService.updateDocument(JSON.stringify(elaticDoc), req.body.Category)
          console.log(elasticResult,'elasticResult')
        }
        else {
          console.log('Here.... ADD')
          const savedProduct = await ProductModel.createPayload(result);
          let elaticDoc = await this.createElasticDocData(savedProduct);
          elaticDoc.id = result._id;
          elaticDoc = new Elastic(elaticDoc);
          elasticResult = await elasticService.createDocument(JSON.stringify(elaticDoc), req.body.Category)
        }
        const response = new Response(1, "Product is saved successfully", "", "", { product: result, elasticResult: elasticResult });
        return res.status(200).send(response);
      }
      const response = new Response(0, "Error in saving Product", 0, "Product not saved", {});
      return res.status(200).send(response);
    } catch (error) {
      const response = new Response(0, "Unexpected Error", 0, error, {});
      return res.status(400).send(response);
    }
  }
```

'''

This is the elasticappsearch file where above mentioned is coming from and for some reason it's not working after axios.patch part.

'''
const private_key = process.env.elastic_private_key
const search_key = process.env.elastic_search_key

```
const axios = require("axios")

class ElasticAppSearch {

 async updateDocument(body, engine) {
        console.log('Its coming in updateDOCS here')
        const response = await axios.patch(`${process.env.elastic_url}/${engine}/documents`, body, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${private_key}`,
            },
        });
        console.log(response,'<--===-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-response')
        return response.data
    }
```

'''

Comment: Private key is a variable which has been definedon the top i did'nt enter it.